# QImage byteCount() is not equal to Width * Height for 8-bit gray image

Tags: c++, qt

I have a few  grayscale 8-bit images of size 450*450 px. How many bytes should be in data in this case? I guess that is 202500, but QImage's method byteCount() gives me 203400. Why?

```
  QImage tmp(fname);
  tmp.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8);//it's not necessary
  int W=tmp.width();//450
  int H=tmp.height();//450
  int ImgSize=tmp.byteCount();//203400
```

It seems like Image has 452*450 size.

Comment: This is because each line in the image is aligned to a particular requirement. In this case 4 bytes which may be a requirement of the video hardware, windowing system, the CPU architecture, or the underlying libraries being used.

Comment: I agree with above comment, to prove that  check what `bytesPerLine` returns (I'm pretty sure it is 452).